# Aligning Form button within nav bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a bit stuck with how to properly align a button on a nav-bar, where the button is wrapped inside a form.

Here is the markup I have (and here is a jsfiddle if its easier: https://jsfiddle.net/darrelltunnell/DTcHh/24292/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top gcs-navbar" id="main-menu">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed main-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <span class="navbar-brand">               
                Test               
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">            
        <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                    <li><a href="@menuItem.Path">One</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="@menuItem.Path">Two</a> </li>
                    <li><a href="@menuItem.Path">Three</a> </li>

                     <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">
                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
               Daz
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link" style="border: none;padding-right:20px">Logout</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that both the anchor and the button (within the form) are not aligning correctly with the other nav items.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<ul>` tag like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
```

Your Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top gcs-navbar" id="main-menu">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed main-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <span class="navbar-brand"> Test </span>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar.in" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li>
                    <a href="@menuItem.Path">One</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="@menuItem.Path">Two</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="@menuItem.Path">Three</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage"> <span class="fa fa-user"></span> Daz </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link" style="border: none;padding-right:20px">
                            Logout
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```